# How do you remove two digits in smallmoney with tsql?

Tags: t-sql

Sign. My tsql kungfu sucks. I have a fee that is of type small money. When I exported as SQL from MS Access the column that represents the fee was stored as text, for example $3.28 was stored as "00000328". When I imported this into MS SQLServer I changed the data type to smallmoney, but it was stored as 328. How do I make all the values on that column to move the "." two digits over to the left.

Answer (score 2):

divide by 100

Comment: seriously..."how do i turn 328 into 3.28?"...did this guy flunk out of third grade math?

Comment: @davr, I wasn't sure how to ask the question and English is not my primary language. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this should do the trick.  Only run it once, though.  Replace "table" with the name of your table and "fee" with the name of your column.

```
update table
set fee = fee / 100.0
```